# Why removes Bokeh hours from DateTimeTIckFormatter after some seconds

Tags: python, bokeh, datetime-format

I'm building a line chart using bokeh.
In X axis I m plotting datetime values. I have also create a DateTimeTickFormatter to display label of this axis:

DateTimeTickFormatter is this:

```
 dateTimeTickFormatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(
        hours="%H:%M:%S",
        minutes="%H:%M:%S",
        seconds="%H:%M:%S")
```

At first time, the chart is plotted like this:
[image]

This chart have an AjaxDataSource to print new point of the lines. After some period, the label of x axis are printed in this mode:
[image]

As you can see, bokeh remove hours from the label. Is there is a way to fixed this strange behaviour?